# Shiny app issue - Reading data into a server.R function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a  list of 4 large dataframes (size 5.9MB compressed) in an Rdata file (dtall.RData) that I am trying to read into  my server.R function using the code provided below, but get "ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer" error message" and the file is read as a single character "dtall"

When I separately load the dtall.RData into r global environment the app runs locally. But as soon as I clear the dtall.RDdata file from the global environment and try to get the app to load it and run I get the error message above.

I have tried using readRDS, but that does not work either, I get error message:
"Error in readRDS("data/dtall.RData") : unknown input format

The file dtall.RData loads correctly outside the shiny scripts by using function load("data/dtall.RData"

Below is the code of my server.R function

```
server.R

predictor <-source("predictor.R")
dtall <- load("data/dtall.RData")


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    wordPrediction <- reactive({
            text <- input$input
            wordPrediction <- predictor(text)})
    output$Prediction <- renderPrint(wordPrediction())

})
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You make a wrong use of both `source` and `load` functions. The `load` function *creates* objects in the environments it is called and *returns* the names of the object created. So, your `dtall` variable is just the name of the object contained in the file. What's worse, if the file contained a `dtall` object, that object is overwritten and cannot be retrieved. See `?load`. Guess you just need the `load(...)` part without assigning the value back to anything.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have removed the assign but I still get error message when runnig the app (error: object 'dtall' not found) the code load(....) works perfect outside the app script

Comment: For the sake of closing my own question. I resolved the problem by moving the data load from the server.R file to a global.R file. It is loading now.